# Getting rid of transparency effect on tumblr theme?

Tags: jquery, css, themes, tumblr

I would like to get rid of an effect that comes default on my theme, since I just started learning I can't seem to find the script that controls the transparency of the menu when on hover. This is the [tumblr](http://bitacora-fotografica.tumblr.com)

How should the coding that controls this effect looks like? So that I can disable it or simply take it away?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you'd like to make the menu appear as soon as the cursor is placed on the `Collection` text and not like it does right now with a `fade-in` effect. Adding this CSS at the bottom of your stylesheet will make you achieve the aforementioned:

```
#base .rent {
     transition: none !important;
}
```

Comment: If the op adds this at the bottom of the stylesheet, why use `!important`? Did we forget about the cascade?

Comment: @mikedidthis Defining the `transition` property as `none` without an `!important` for `#base .rent` doesn't work in OP's website, I've posted the above answer after testing using developer tools.

Comment: Ahh, damn I didn't see the `id`. Would be nicer to use something like: `#relative-header #base .rent` and use specificity over brute force. Either way, upvote incoming...

Answer (score 0):

It's done with a simple css hover effect. The moment you hover on div#base, the *opacity* of div.rent will be set to 1.

**HTML**

```
<div id="base">
    <div class="rent">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* normal state */
#base .rent{
    opacity: 0;
}

/* hover state */
#base:hover .rent{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**transition: all 1s ease-out** causes the easing effect.
If you don't want it to be transparent, simply change **opacity: 0** to **opacity: 1** on #base .rent